# Bluetooth file transfer in shell script

Tags: bluetooth

I'd like to send files to my phone via bluetooth using a bash script or something similar. The ussp-push utility works, but I find it is much slower than the "Send To"  option in gnome. Is there a way to use gnome's bluetooth functionality from a shell scirpt?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`bluetooth-sendto --device=12:34:56:78:9A:BC filename` works for me. "12:34:56:78:9A:BC" is the Bluetooth device address (bdaddr) of the device. You can get the bdaddr with `hcitool scan`.

Comment: Note that the bluetooth-sendto command opens a dialog which shows the progress of the file transfer, so it cannot be used from a headless display. However, it is perfect for my use case.

Comment: This is a nautilus plugin command that was removed, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's in the gnome-bluetooth package in Ubuntu 16.04.