# How do you make Ubuntu Server accept files sent over bluetooth?

Tags: server, bluetooth

How do you configure Ubuntu Server to automatically receive files over Bluetooth and save them with no user interaction?

This question is almost identical to [this question from 2 years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131570/how-do-you-make-ubuntu-accept-files-sent-over-bluetooth), but relates to Ubuntu Server, where no GUI is available.

Edit: To clarify, this question is not about pairing Bluetooth devices, but about making an Ubuntu Server machine automatically accept Bluetooth file transfers. This question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution that @wilf and I found was to install `obexpushd`, a daemon that will accept incoming OBEX (and therefore Bluetooth) file transfers and save the files to its working directory.

Just `apt-get install obexpushd`, and run it in the directory you want the files to be saved in. Or, if you'd like it to start with your machine, here's a simple Upstart job file that should do the trick:

> chdir /home/USERNAME
>   exec obexpushd -n
>   start on startup

Save the above as `/etc/init/obexpushd.conf` (making sure to change the first line to point to the directory you'd like the files to be saved), run `initctl reload-configuration`, and `start obexpushd`.

Once you've paired your Bluetooth device with your machine, you should be able to send files to it without having to manually accept the transfer.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look in [`dconf-editor`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor/) and...

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing bluetooth-obexpush-enabled VALUE
```

Is the equivalent to 'Receive files in Downloads folder over Bluetooth', `VALUE` can be `true` or `false`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing bluetooth-obexpush-enabled VALUE
```

Is the same as 'Notify about received files', `VALUE` of `true` or `false` again.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing bluetooth-accept-files
```

is the same as the 'Accept files:' selection box, `VALUE` can be `always`, `bonded` *(Only work for set-up devices)* and `ask`.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lu54D.png) is the picture from the other question in case you need it.

You can find what the current values are using `get` in place of `set`, To reset, use `reset` instead.

To list the available options:

```
$ gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing
bluetooth-accept-files
bluetooth-allow-write
bluetooth-enabled
bluetooth-notify
bluetooth-obexpush-enabled
bluetooth-require-pairing
enabled
require-password
```

Here also is a list with possible values in bold

> org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing bluetooth-accept-files **always bonded ask**
>   org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing bluetooth-allow-write **true false**
>   org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing bluetooth-enabled **true false**
>   org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing bluetooth-notify **true false**
>   org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing bluetooth-obexpush-enabled **true false**
>   org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing bluetooth-require-pairing **true false**
>   org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing enabled **true false**
>   org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing require-password **never on_write always**

More can be found using `man gsettings`

Hope this helps ;D - *Not as though I am doing this just because I use a netbook with a broken display for file sharing, for which this could be rather helpful...*

---

As the above answer will probably only work if you have a graphical Gnome-based desktop installed, a simpler thing may be to use `bluez` as in the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187092/bluetooth-from-the-command-line-in-12-04/187100#187100).

Comment: `org.gnome.desktop`? I don't have Gnome installed since this is a server; will the Bluetooth system read the configuration from there regardless? I can't test it at the moment.

Comment: I have tested this and it seems to work - I do have Gnome installed, though this in Unity... Unity is a derivative of Gnome, so they seem to share the same settings.

Comment: While your answer is probably helpful to some, I just checked, and my server doesn't even have dconf installed, so I don't think this will work.

Comment: No you don't need it installed, it is just the graphical interface for `gsettings`, I linked it as then you can use it on an Ubuntu which has a graphical interface if you want. It works without Gnome, on the netbook I referred to in my answer, but you do need to be logged in. By the way, you may be interested in [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/187100/178596) answer in another question.

Comment: I went ahead and installed `libglib2.0-bin` which provides the gsettings executable. Unfortunately, running `gsettings list-schemas` reveals that there is no `org.gnome.desktop.file-sharing` schema. Should I create the schema and populate it with the default values manually?

Comment: You could install the Unity or Gnome desktops, which would probably add it... But that may be uncessary - you can check with `gsettings list-schemas |` **`grep file-sharing`**

Comment: That returns no results. There is no file-sharing schema.

Comment: I did add an edit to the bottom of my answer that may be of help...

Comment: The question you linked doesn't mention anything about file transfers at all, only pairing.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/41050/178596 ? Receiving file transfers generally seems to automatically be sent to a particular folder. If not you can use `obexpushd`, which will run a deamon to receive files - http://debaira.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/bluetooth-command-line.html . These can all be installed easily using `sudo apt-get install...`.

Comment: Thanks wilf, I found obexpushd a few hours ago and it seems to be working fine; just finished writing an upstart job for it. I came back here to write up a quick answer for it, but if you want credit for it, go ahead and submit something, and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: It be best for you to do an answer, as I can't test it as the only Linux machine I have with functioning bluetooth is the aforementioned Netbook, which is running an old Fedora release, not Ubuntu. You also then get credit for it ;-)